# How to implement plyr.js within a Rails 6 site?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, webpacker, plyr.js

https://plyr.io/ is a javascript library to play videos with support for YouTube and Vimeo. I'm trying to implement it within a Rails 6 site. What are the steps to make this happen?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rails 6 using webpacker to manage their assets, to install `plyr` you just need install it through package manager:

```
yarn add plyr
```

then you can require it in your js file like the docs:

```js
import Plyr from 'plyr';
 
const player = new Plyr('#player');
```

make sure you have run webpacker dev server, if not you may getting module not found. Hope this help, correct me if there is any mistake.

Comment: I also wanted to mention for anyone reading this information that the CSS file should also be included in some way. For example a CDN link in app/views/layout.html.haml: %link{:href => "https://cdn.plyr.io/3.6.2/plyr.css", :rel => "stylesheet"}/

Answer (score 2):

There are many ways to including the plyr.js to your project and then use it.

I'm covering one of the methods to include plyr.js into your project:

Step 1.
Download Plyr.js from its website or from the cdn link https://cdn.plyr.io/3.6.2/plyr.js

Step 2.
Place the plyr.js file inside `app/assets/javascripts` folder

Step 3. You need to mention plyr.js in your manifest file so it can be used in your app. Add the following line (without the extension) to your manifest file (`app/assets/javascripts/application.js`)

```
//= require plyr
```

Now Plyr js available to you for usage and can be used as usual. You can create `<video>` tags inside your erb to bring up the player.

Eg.

```
<video id="player" playsinline controls data-poster="/path/to/poster.jpg">
  <source src="/path/to/video.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
  <source src="/path/to/video.webm" type="video/webm" />
</video>
```

Comment: Thanks Kumar, but I think you're describing the Rails 5 way. I need the webpacker style for Rails 6. In Rails 6 we don't have an app/assets/javascripts folder anymore.